# Why I get this error ? expected an indented block (<unknown>, line 106)pylint(syntax-error)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to run this python file, I'm new programming with python when I try to run this file in the terminal or execute directly (double click on file)
I get this error:

```
File "C:\Users\benja\code\orig-master\data_new_score.py", line 106
l.append(info_cc_d  w(loan_id).values())
^
```

My File

```
import pandas as pd
import yaml
import MySQLdb
import datetime

loan_ids = ['10003395','10008588','10008591','10008611','10008638','10008653','10008665','10008674','10008675','10013191','10003674','10003689','10003692','10003711','10003716','10003722','10003728','10003733','10003739','10003776','10003785','10003820','10003822','10003827','10003309','10003316','10003327','10003348','10005950']

columns = info_cc_dw('10003391').keys()
l=[info_cc_dw('10003391').values()]

for loan_id in loan_ids:
l.append(info_cc_d  w(loan_id).values())

data = pd.DataFrame(l,columns=columns)
data.to_csv('test_dw.csv')
```

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: The content of a `for` loop must be indented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import yaml
import MySQLdb
import datetime

loan_ids = ['10003395','10008588','10008591','10008611','10008638','10008653','10008665','10008674','10008675','10013191','10003674','10003689','10003692','10003711','10003716','10003722','10003728','10003733','10003739','10003776','10003785','10003820','10003822','10003827','10003309','10003316','10003327','10003348','10005950']

columns = info_cc_dw('10003391').keys()
l=[info_cc_dw('10003391').values()]

for loan_id in loan_ids:
  l.append(info_cc_d  w(loan_id).values())

data = pd.DataFrame(l,columns=columns)
data.to_csv('test_dw.csv')
```

As you can see, I have indented the line after your **for loop**. This is just part of the python syntax.